# Elasticsearch Geo Centroid Aggregation with C# Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Im trying to build a geo centroid aggregation with the C# Nest Library, like this:

```
{
  "query": {"match_all":{}},
  "aggregations": {
    "myGrid": {
      "geohash_grid": {
        "field": "location",
        "precision": 6
      },
      "aggs": {
        "myCentroid": {
          "geo_centroid": {
            "field": "location"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it seems that this aggregation type don't supported by Nest. How do I build this aggregation with Nest?

I'm using NEST 2.3.2 and ES 2.2

Comment: what version of NEST are you using and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: i have added the versions to the question

Comment: Yep, looks like it's missing right now :/ - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/aggregations.html

Comment: Added a PR for this to go into next 2.x release - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/2118

Comment: thank you very much